# Installing Berkeley DB 4.8 on Windows

Tags: installation, mingw, berkeley-db, msys

I am trying to install Berkeley DB 4.8.30 on my Windows 10 computer. The project is located in E:\deps\db-4.8.30.NC. I am using the MinGW msys program to do the installation and I run the following commands:

```
cd /e/deps/db-4.8.30.NC/build_unix
../dist/configure --enable-mingw --enable-cxx --disable-shared --disable-replication
make
```

The configuration seems to be working fine based on the response, but when I try to make it, it will not succesfully compile. I get the following output after running the make command:

```
./libtool --mode=compile gcc -c -I. -I../dist/..  -O3  ../dist/../mutex/mut_fail
chk.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -c -I. -I../dist/.. -O3 ../dist/../mutex/mut_failchk.c -o
 mut_failchk.o
../dist/../mutex/mut_failchk.c: I funktion ö__mut_failchkö:
../dist/../mutex/mut_failchk.c:53:27: fel: inkompatibel typ f÷r argument 3 av öd
benv->is_aliveö
       dbenv, mutexp->pid, 0, DB_MUTEX_PROCESS_ONLY))
                           ^
../dist/../mutex/mut_failchk.c:53:27: anm: ödb_threadid_t {õven struct <anonym>}
ö f÷rvõntades men argumentet har typ öintö
../dist/../mutex/mut_failchk.c:57:51: fel: inkompatibel typ f÷r argument 3 av öd
benv->thread_id_stringö
       dbenv->thread_id_string(dbenv, mutexp->pid, 0, buf));
                                                   ^
../dist/../mutex/mut_failchk.c:57:51: anm: ödb_threadid_t {õven struct <anonym>}
ö f÷rvõntades men argumentet har typ öintö
make: *** [mut_failchk.o] Error 1
```

I have looked around for hours but I cannot find a solution that works for me yet. What can I try to get it working?